# GSON - the Array<>Object JSON-Conversion is not solved despite TypeAdapter

Tags: java, android, gson

This is my class which represents the json-structure from the server:

```
ArrayList<EventWebInterface.Element> element;

public class Element {
    String id;
    String subtitle;
    String name;
    String subline;
    String count;
}
```

And this is the structure:

```
{
    element: [
    {
    id: "1985",
    subtitle: "01. August 2013 18:30 Uhr | Berlin",
    name: "blabla....",
subline: "blabla....",
    category_id: ""
    },
    {
    id: "1962",
    subtitle: "07. August 2013 19:00 Uhr | Cloppenburg",
    name: "blabla...",
    subline: "blabla....",
    category_id: ""
    },
    { ...
```

But sometimes the structure has only one element like:

```
{
    element: {
       id: "1985",
       subtitle: "01. August 2013 18:30 Uhr | Berlin",
       name: "blabla...",
       subline: "blabla....",
       category_id: ""
    }
}
```

For this case i've got a typeadapter for gson which looks like this:

```
public class EventWebTypeAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<List<EventWebInterface.Element>> {
public List<EventWebInterface.Element> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext ctx) {
    List<EventWebInterface.Element> vals = new ArrayList<EventWebInterface.Element>();
    if (json.isJsonArray()) {
        for (JsonElement e : json.getAsJsonArray()) {
            vals.add((EventWebInterface.Element) ctx.deserialize(e, EventWebInterface.Element.class));
        }
    } else if (json.isJsonObject()) {
        vals.add((EventWebInterface.Element) ctx.deserialize(json, EventWebInterface.Element.class));
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected JSON type: " + json.getClass());
    }
    return vals;
}

public Type getType(){
    return new TypeToken<List<EventWebInterface.Element>>() {}.getType();
}
```

}

I use it this way:

```
EventWebTypeAdapter mTypeAdapter = new EventWebTypeAdapter();
Type mType = mTypeAdapter.getType();
Class<I> mInterface = EventWebInterface.class

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(mType, mTypeadapter).create();
dataObject = gson.fromJson(data, mInterface);
```

But the Adapter doesn't work. It gives me:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

I don't get it, why it doesn't work... =(

Comment: Please add the code where you declare `mType`, `mTypeAdapter` and `mInterface`...

Comment: The declaration is in another function:
`EventWebTypeAdapter mTypeAdapter = new EventWebTypeAdapter();
Type mType = mTypeAdapter.getType();
Class<I> mInterface  = EventWebInterface.class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself find your code a bit messy, so I can't really find the error.

I'll explain what I'd do from the beginning and maybe you can compare it with your code and get some ideas...

First I'd create these 2 classes:

```
class Response
    List<Element> element;

class Element
    String id;
    String subtitle;
    String name;
    String subline;
    String count;
```

Then I'd create a `TypeAdapter`, and I think the easiest way is to create one for the `Response`class. Something like:

```
public class ResponseDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Response> {

    public Response deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext ctx) {

        JsonElement elementField = json.getAsJsonObject().get("element");

        List<Element> elementList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (elementField.isJsonArray()) {
            for (JsonElement item : elementField.getAsJsonArray()) {
                elementList.add(ctx.deserialize(item, Element.class));
            }
        } else if (elementField.isJsonObject()) {
            elementList.add(ctx.deserialize(elementField, Element.class));
        }

        Response response = new Response(elementList);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to register the adapter with:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Response.class, new ResponseDeserializer());
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

And eventually parse the JSON with:

```
Response response = gson.fromJson(data, Response.class);
```

Comment: Okay, but i overwrite the method getType in TypeAdapter with: `public Type getType(){
    return new TypeToken<List<EventWebInterface.Element>>() {}.getType();
}` see my 4th code-block

Comment: @Osiriz, you're indeed right! See edited answer, it's the best I can do, because I can't find the error in your code... I hope this helps...

Comment: Hey MikO! THX! Your edited answer works like a charm. I changed my TypeAdapter with yours and nothing else. It's difficult to show sourcecode in different classes on stackoverflow and taking only the interesting lines. Maybe it seems to be messy therefore.